# Angular Material Not Working in Some Components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Sorry if this is hard to follow, but I'm confused why my code is working in some components, but not others. I imported `MdButtonModule` into my `app.module.ts` file and was able to get the following code to work in my `app.component.html` file:

```
<button md-button>Click Me!</button>
```

When I tried the same code in a component called `shifts.component.html`, it didn't work. `shifts.component.ts` is imported in `shifts.module.ts` and `shifts.module.ts` is imported in `app.module.ts`. It turns out that I had to import `MdButtonModule` into `shifts.module.ts` in order to use Angular Material buttons in `shifts.component.html`. Shouldn't I be able to use Angular Material buttons in any component if I import it in `app.module.ts`? Something doesn't seem right. What am I not understanding?

Comment: You have to import MD module, they are not "inherited"

Comment: The modules are encapsulated items. They do not share data with imported modules. If you want to use data from some module, you have to import it in the module you have to use it.

Comment: Share your `app.module.ts`...that will help us to help you.

Comment: I observed that when my_own_component that uses material was NOT part of [declarations] and [exports] sections of the module, none of the controls worked. Ideally the component should have been unrecognized resulting in error. But for me, it didn't happen. Instead only 'materials' did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of information taken from [Official Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

**Step 3: Import the component modules**

```
Import the NgModule for each component you want to use:

import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
  ...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

Alternatively, you can create a separate NgModule that imports all of the Angular Material components that you will use in your application. You can then include this module wherever you'd like to use the components.

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
  exports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
})
export class MyOwnCustomMaterialModule { }
```

Whichever approach you use, be sure to import the Angular Material modules after Angular's BrowserModule, as the import order matters for NgModules.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever decided to create a separated module as suggested by @Nour, here's a better approach so you don't repeat the MatModules in the import/exports.

**material.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

const material: any[] = [
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatSnackBarModule
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [material],
  exports: [material]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```